# How to add padding to a slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-feed, jquery-slider

On this page:
http://texting2web.co.cc/ (ignore the domain name, still waiting for my TLD to transfer :P)

I have a Twitter slider, but I want it to have padding. Whenever I try to add padding to it, it cuts off for some reason. Ive tried a lot of different ways but to no avail.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried.

Comment: Adding padding in the .twitter-box-wrapper doesn't work ?

Comment: Ive tried just normal padding, but it gets cut off on the right, I've tried the padding, and then reducing the size of the box, it does the padding correctly but it gets cut off at the right still. I also tried having another div inside the box and applied padding, but that had the same effect, it gets cut off to the right.

Comment: @warface: That increases the box size, which messes up the whole layout :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I had to decrease the div within the twitter box by 20px, and then add a `margin-left: 10px;` to simulate a 10px padding.